# JPA insert identity id starts at 0 instead of 1?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot

I have a problem when I am inserting an new entity to a table in SQL Server, even when I set these annotation for my PK entity in java code.

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
```

The index still started at 0, this case always happens when I drop and re-create table (when identity is set to null) and use insert by JPA repository. (index start at 1 when I used insert statement at Microsoft SSMS).
But when I delete table's data and use `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table', RESEED, 0);`, then index of inserted record is 1.

Here is my CREATE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_member_info](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [type] [int] NULL,
    [id_card_number] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [prefix] [int] NULL,
    [first_name] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [last_name] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [dob] [datetime] NULL,
    [email_personal] [varchar](70) NULL
)
```

Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Please show the CREATE statement of the table

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I've just added Create statement above, can you please check for me?

Comment: Genuine question: _**why**_ does this matter? An `IDENTITY` is a surrogate key after all.

Comment: There are some features that I cannot reference data with id = 0, this problem end up at the end of project. When I drop and recreate database to refresh data, then id start 0 so I just need to fix this :(